# What are those large poles for that are always in front of US stand-alone store buildings?

Tags: structures, building-design

Screenshot of a video where they are featured in the background: [image]

They appear to have no electronics built in, such as an electric charge station, or a parking ticket dispenser or something like that.

They appear to just be large, solid metal poles that are roughly placed with one per parking space in front of the store.

Are they a safety measure? So that nobody can drive like a madman into the store? Is that really so common as to have them waste all that money on "safety poles" everywhere?

Are they meant for bicycles to lean against them? For people to hang out in that area? Resting against them? Are they purely ornamental? Are they considered aesthetically pleasing?

Comment: These bollards in literally every country on Earth. Also popular, say, next to petrol pumps.

Comment: They can be used aesthetically.  Target usually has large red spheres serving the same purpose.

Comment: If it's 2 for $3.33, how much is 1?

Comment: Illuminati Obelisks for poor people.

Comment: You guessed it.  They are there to prevent drivers from driving into the store, deliberately or not.  You can also find them at gas stations and near truck loading zones among other places.

Comment: Sorry I could not find a picture, but I recall some time ago that the Australians used a bollard in the countryside that was an L-shape underground and flipped up and skewered the vehicle. It could be used in loose sand where a good foundation was difficult to obtain.

Comment: @PonderStibbons I'm Australian and I have never heard of that. It sounds completely illegal.

Comment: @user207421 It might have been illegal. It was in an article in an Australian newspaper in the 1980s. Farmers had put them in because large off road vehicles had been pushing down gates on their properties. But, I can offer no further evidence. I did some searching, but found no reference.

Answer (score 38):

They are called bollards.

Their function is to provide safety for pedestrians from traffic, distracted drivers who may encroach into the sidewalk, or runaway cars e.g a driver who inadvertently leaves his/her car in neutral without the emergency brake set.

Many municipalities require them and have codes and specifications defining their dimensions and strength.

Comment: could have sworn there are a remedy of the cowboy-era ^^ so you have a place to bind your horse while shopping  ;-)

Comment: Also, it's not like they're THAT expensive compared to the rest of the construction. The US is rich af

Comment: @user91988 They are aren't particularly unique to the US.  I'm not sure if they're even much of a good indicator that a country has money.  It shows they have enough money that some people have cars; but it's not like it would be that expensive to build the bollards.

Comment: They can be _incredibly_ strong: https://giphy.com/gifs/whoa-truck-bollard-j0HCppaqMcM3C

Comment: You only really see them at storefronts with their own car parking directly in front of the building entrance. Parking on other sides of the building won't have bollards, even if there's a pedestrian walkway. Often places will have a high-enough sidewalk curb or will use alternatives, such as stylish concrete blocks or heavy-duty plant pots.

Comment: @minnmass Wow. I don't know how many years it took, but thanks to you, now I've finally seen how that video ends.

Comment: CAn you cite anything supporting their presence for defending the entrance against a car running into it? In my experience they are there simply to prevent people from parking in spots they aren' t supposed to, because people are lazy and will think they can just park for five minutes directly in front of the store.

Comment: @minnmass and sadly it demonstrates that enough sub-munitions in the back of the lorry mean the pole fails to protect the inside of the store :)

Answer (score 29):

They are called Bollards. But these aren't *defensive* as suggested.

### Look closer.  There's no curb.

This is a new style of store (from the architecture) and **curbs have been eliminated for ADA reasons** (benefit of wheelchairs).

As such, there is literally nothing to prevent a car from drifting forward and hitting the building; *it's not even clear where you should stop the nose of your car*. There's clearly intended to be a sidewalk there, but **lots of people** will simply pull right up and block the sidewalk.  I see it all the time, and often have to walk around the offending car. Hence, the bollards.

The benefit (ADA-wise) is that wheelchair users and other limited-ability people *are not confined to using the "handicap spaces" - and can park anywhere and directly access the sidewalk.  This is consistent with US "ADA 2.0"* doctrine that people in wheelchairs should be able to use the same route as everyone else.

### These bollards are *not* a fortification.

Keep in mind, OP's example is an ordinary convenience store.  It lacks any particular national importance; it's not a gathering point for *tens* of people let alone *thousands*. [Ram-raiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram-raiding) are not an issue here, since that is to penetrate locked doors in empty stores, and **these stores are open 24x7**.

Here's how you can tell. There are clearly marked parking spaces, *and the bollards are set on the center-line of the parking space*.  The design really depends on cars at least making some attempt to park inside the lines.

Bare minimum width of a parking space is 8.5 feet (2600mm), because you need at least 24" (600mm) width to open the car door.  Well the bollards are typically <12" (300mm)wide, and these look like 6" trade size pipe (168.3mm).  That means with the standard "guard a curbless sidewalk" bollards, **you can easily drive a car between them**.

So, completely worthless as a fortification.

When you look at bollards *as* fortifications, there's less than 5 feet (1500mm) between them. Further, this 6" pipe wouldn't do - even filled with concrete, it's just too flimsy.

---

---

---

* ADA 2.0 isn't really a thing, I just made that up as a slang way to talk about it. What is true is that there was a major shift in ADA doctrine, as they discovered that (gosh) wheelchair users rarely travel alone - and often travel with others in wheelchairs, and that tends to overwhelm *limited* accommodations like lifts tacked onto stairs.

- Initially, ADA was to provide access *at all*. Abled people could climb the magnificent steps, and wheelchair users go around the back of the (older) building by the dumpsters and people shooting up, and push a buzzer and wait 5 minutes to have a guard escort them through the non-public areas, and it's 15 minutes before they actually catch up with their friends.
- The new doctrine is that wheelchair users are equals. You're not allowed to build the grand staircase, and you cannot create barriers that would send wheelchair users on a different path.  Curbless construction is consistent with the new doctrine.

Comment: Please note that the ADA does not only help create equality for people in wheelchairs.  It's for all disabilities.  These particular changes also help people who depend on walkers, canes, scooters, or crutches, as well as people who have motor impairments or difficulty lifting their legs as high as others.  Whether or not they help or hurt people who are blind or have limited vision is open for discussion.

Comment: looke closer thiese is a curb., it stats behind the puddle

Comment: @Jasen Yeah I saw that, but it's anomalous. It doesn't go all the way across to the left. It looks like some sort of portable ramp

Comment: The "puddle" and "ramp" can be alternatively seen as the windscreen and bonnet/boot of a parked motor vehicle.  (-:

Comment: completely false assertion that it is not defensive. see my answer below.

Comment: @likejudo: "*... see my answer below.*" only makes sense if you expect that your post won't get voted up. Posts are sorted by votes and user sorting preferences.

Comment: @likejudo I am only talking about OP's building, which uses cheap pipes unfit for defense.

Comment: It's also worth noting that most ADA improvements benefit _everyone_, not only people who have a disability.  It's easier to carry heavy boxes in or out of the store if you don't have to mount a curb you might not even see.  It's easier to use the elevator than the stairs.  It's easier to get in and out of a tub in a hotel using the hand rails, even if you don't have a disability that makes it impossible without the hand rails.  People often overlook the fact that an ADA improvement benefits more than just the disabled.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Do you know of any articles that discuss this shift in thinking about the ADA that you've termed "ADA 2.0"?  I'd be interested in reading more about it.

Answer (score 9):

[Bollards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollard) and other defensive oriented structures significantly predate the 2016 Nice attacks. They have been in place at the construction of many buildings in the US and across the world for decades including government and multi-national corporation buildings. You probably just never noticed them.

It is my opinion that you see more of the type above due to the rising prevalence of reckless and distracted driving. The kind of bollard shown above will stop cars and small trucks as long as they are not traveling at a significant rate of speed.

[image]

**NYC Federal Reserve**

[image]

**IBM Armonk**

[image]

**Herbert Hoover Building Washington DC**

[image]

**Arc de Triomphe**

Many other methods are used as well including fences with raised stone or concrete bases and berms or trenches depending on the available terrain.

[Protect Buildings from Vehicle Attacks [2012]](https://www.buildings.com/article-details/articleid/13693/title/protect-buildings-from-vehicle-attacks)

Comment: +1 for showing this is not just a US-specific concept

Answer (score 4):

They are to prevent "smash and rob". A situation where someone steals a vehicle and drives through a store front to rob the store. Usually an accomplice drives a second vehicle to escape.

Comment: And just check youtube for cases of robbery or bad drivers hitting the wrong pedal...

Comment: The main value of the car smashing through is to gain physical access. But  that doesn't make much sense in OP's application, which is a convenience store that is open 24x7. A more likely reason is they no longer have **curbs** for benefit of wheelchairs, yet they need a way to keep honest cars from accidentally hitting the nicely finished (and expensive to repair) building, or God help you, *the rack of propane tanks*....

Comment: They see far more use against accidental crashes than against deliberate ones.  Checking my local police blotter, I see nearly two dozen vehicle-versus-store crashes since the start of the year, and not one of them has an accompanying theft.

Comment: I guess I watch too much security camera footage on TV. But it is funny to see "smash and grab" robbers  smash into a convenience store and try to pick up a cash machine as if it were a chair ( they are well anchored into concrete).

Answer (score 3):

For safety. They are to protect whatever is behind them from cars. They're very strong and will stop or slow down a car that would otherwise cause a lot of damage or risk to life.

Answer (score 3):

Bollards in Switzerland have been placed to prevent and hinder drivers from parking vehicles with 2 wheels on the pavement or to stop them from parking their cars in front of shops.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have covered a lot of the original use cases but nowadays terrorism is one of the big reasons why you see them being put up just about everywhere.  According to this article, the more study ones are designed to stop a loaded truck up to 80 mph: https://www.sdmmag.com/articles/97143-anti-terrorism-bollard-manufacturer-helps-secure-2-iconic-us-locations

I don't know for certain but I believe the Nice, France terror attack was a huge driver in their proliferation.

Comment: High speed vehicles being used as rams goes back to the first mechanization (horses would refuse). And America went nuts with bollards and zigzags approaching guard shacks right after 9/11 and in some cases well before.  The Federal Reserve has always been kings of that. I can tell you Target's round bollards are fairly new.  But pre-2016.

Answer (score 1):

At Sprint, the telecom company's headquarters in Overland Park, KS when they built their billion $$$ campus in 2001, the CEOs and Executive building had a separate entrance and these bollards. It was expressly there to prevent truck and car bombs.

For those who only think of 9/11, [remember the truck bombing by Iran in Beirut, Lebanon in the 1980s which killed 241 US marines and soldiers](https://www.historynet.com/1983-beirut-bombing-the-blt-building-is-gone.htm).

Never Forget.

> Marine sentries initially paid little attention to the Mercedes truck.
>   Heavy vehicles were a common sight at the airport, and in fact the BLT
>   was expecting one that day with a water delivery. The truck circled
>   the parking lot, then picked up speed as it traveled parallel to a
>   line of concertina wire protecting the south end of the Marine
>   compound. Suddenly, the vehicle veered left, plowed through the
>   5-foot-high wire barrier and rumbled between two guard posts.
>
> By then it was obvious the driver of the truck—a bearded man with
>   black hair—had hostile intentions, but there was no way to stop him.
>   The Marines were operating under peacetime rules of engagement, and
>   their weapons were not loaded. Lance Corporal Eddie DiFranco, manning
>   the sentry post on the driver’s side of the truck, soon guessed the
>   driver’s horrifying purpose. “He looked right at me…smiled, that’s
>   it,” DiFranco later recalled. “Soon as I saw [the truck] over here, I
>   knew what was going to happen.” By the time he managed to slap a
>   magazine into his M16 and chamber a round, the truck had roared
>   through an open vehicle gate, rumbled past a long steel pipe barrier,
>   threaded between two other pipes and was closing on the BLT barracks.
>
> Sergeant of the guard Stephen Russell was alone at his
>   sandbag-and-plywood post at the front of the building but facing
>   inside. Hearing a revving engine, he turned to see the Mercedes truck
>   barreling straight toward him. He instinctively bolted through the
>   lobby toward the building’s rear entrance, repeatedly yelling, “Hit
>   the deck! Hit the deck!” It was futile gesture, given that nearly
>   everyone was still asleep. As Russell dashed out the rear entrance, he
>   looked over his shoulder and saw the truck slam through his post,
>   smash through the entrance and come to a halt in the midst of the
>   lobby. After an ominous pause of a second or two, the truck erupted in
>   a massive explosion—so powerful that it lifted the building in the
>   air, shearing off its steel-reinforced concrete support columns (each
>   15 feet in circumference) and collapsing the structure. Crushed to
>   death within the resulting mountain of rubble were 241 U.S. military
>   personnel—

Comment: You have a datapoint of knowledge use of th***ose*** bollards at Sprint's Overland Park, KS headquarters.  Since you mention this on my answer, I'm disappointed that you conclude that *all* bollards *everywhere* are for that same purpose; they're not. OP has a plain convenience store.  Anyway as I discussed, th***ese*** bollards out of 6" pipe are far too weak for defense.  I don't downvote lightly, and besides, you get full marks for **being the first to mention Beirut**, IMO the true origin of the *defensive bollard* trend.  Net score +1.